# Sequential Random Numbers in C++?

Tags: c++, random, numbers

I'm looking for a way to generate two random numbers quickly in C++. The code is for a die and needs to generate a random number when rolled. My code currently looks like this:

```
Die::Die() {
    srand(time(NULL));
}

void Die::roll() {
    value = rand() % 6 + 1;
}
```

If I create two objects with this code, srand(), being a static (non-instance based) function, will generate a new seed for all objects. I've also tried doing this:

```
void Die::roll() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    value = rand() % 6 + 1;
}
```

Rather then having it in the constructor, but if I call them quickly like follows:

```
die0->roll();
die1->roll();
```

Their values are usually equal. Is there any way to actually make this random, every time? Thanks for all your help. :)

Comment: You only need to seed the random number generator once.  You can easily do this by moving the call `srand(time(NULL))` to the code that initialises your application

Comment: @simonc In fact, he SHOULD only seed it once. As it is now, if called several times in rapid succession, it will be reseeded with the same value over and over.

Comment: You might want to look into the [new PRNG functionality of C++11](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random), especially the [`std::uniform_int_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) class and the example in that link.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yeah, it also avoids modulo bias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the program is running quickly enough, the time (in seconds) will generally be the same, which means your seed will be the same, which means your random values with be the same.
As the commenters have said, do the random seed elsewhere (like the start of your program or thread).

Comment: If I do that, the values of the two Die instances are exactly the same, which is why I tried re-seeding it in the first place.

Comment: That won't be a problem; you don't need to reseed.

Comment: The two Die instances will be the same, but the random number generator will generate a pseudo-random string of numbers (the two Die will pull numbers from the same string of randoms).

Comment: Yep, I figured it out, the issue was that I had the value variable at the top of the .cpp file rather than as a private variable in the header file; that's why the values were the same. I moved the srand() to the start of my program as well. Still getting used to OOP in C++. :) Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, if the srands occur close enough to each other in time, then you are seeding  the rng with the same value, and so the first values you get after each seed will be the same. To avoid this, you can ensure that the seeding only occurs once. For example, you can remove the srand from your Die class, and seed sometime before your first use of Die.

Alternatively, if you don't want the consumer of Die to have the burden of calling srand, you could keep the srand in Die's constructor, but guard against calling it multiple times with a static bool.

```
Die::Die()
{
  static bool seeded = false;
  if (!seeded)
  {
    srand(time(NULL));
    seeded = true;
  }
}
```

Note that this srand can still affect other classes that srand() and rand(), but chances are this wouldn't matter. But if you need a random number within multiple classes that you are defining, you could look at creating an RNG singleton to generate numbers for you.

Comment: A simpler solution would be to have a static variable, with an initializer which calls `srand`.

Answer (score 1):

The least error prone method will be to use [`uniform_int_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) from the [`random`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) header. This also avoids [`modulo bias`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984974/why-do-people-say-there-is-modulo-bias-when-using-a-random-number-generator), this is basic example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

 class Die
 {
   public:
     template <class Generator>
     void roll( Generator &g )
     {
         std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(1,6);
         std::cout << dist(g) ;
     }

   private:

 } ;

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;

    std::mt19937 e1(rd());

    Die d1, d2 ;

    for (int n = 0; n < 10; ++n) {
            d1.roll( e1 ) ;
            std::cout << " , " ;
            d2.roll( e1 ) ;
            std::cout << std::endl ;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can also use `static` members, as James suggests:

```
class Die
{
   public:
     Die()  {} ;

     void roll()
     {
         std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(1,6);
         std::cout << dist(e1) ;
     }

   private:
      static std::random_device rd;    
      static std::mt19937 e1 ;
} ;
```

Comment: Why be simple when one can be complicated, right?  (Why should each instance of `Die` have its own generator, for example?  And why pass the `Generator` as argument each time, rather than using a static member or a singleton?

Comment: @JamesKanze I meant to remove the second generator, the choice of passing the generator was arbitrary and I have added an example using static members.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you don't want to reseed the generator more
than once.  If `Die` is the sole user of `rand` (or even if it
isn't), you can use a variable at name space scope to seed it:

```
int seeded = (srand( time( NULL ) ), rand());
```

Whether this is a good idea or not depends; it makes it
impossible to duplicate a run of your code for debugging
purposes, for example.  If this is an issue, you'll want to 1)
log the seed you use, and 2) add an option to the command line
to specify the seed; the latter means calling `srand` from
`main`.

(Note too that I've added a call to `rand()` in the
initialization.  In at least one wide spread implementation, the
first call to `rand()` returns the seed, which means that it can
be very predictable.)